# Cross validating one values from one column to second column

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I have data in google sheet. I want a way to cross match if values in column 1 is available on any row in column 2. If available either highlight with any colour or just bold it.

Is this possible on google sheets or MS Excel?

Comment: Yes with conditional formatting and custom formula using MATCH or COUNTIF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=IF(ISNA(MATCH($C1,$A$1:$A$8, 0)), "No Match", "Match")`

[image]

Comment: No worries. Make sure you post a copy of your spreadsheet next time to make answering the question easier! Cheers